Task assignment: Equitable and Fair work distribution
A set of workers: $w1, w2, w3, w4$ solve a set of arbitrary no. of tasks: $t_1, t_2, \ldots t_{37}$
Each task has a type, say there are total of 5 types of tasks: $q_1, q_2, q_3, q_4, q_5$ and the tasks are all distributed with these types randomly. A task can have only 1 type.
Requirements:

Only 1 worker per task
All tasks must be assigned
Some tasks must be assigned to specific workers only, this is known
No cost associated with any task or worker at all
All workers should do a similar no. of tasks

Eg: here we have 37 tasks to be divided amongst 4 workers. So each worker should do either 9 or 10 tasks


It should also be ensured that each worker also gets as much variety of query types as possible

This becomes extremely complicated when some tasks are already assigned to some workers as that messes up the equal/similar distribution of task types to each worker



My approach to solve constraint 5:
total_tasks/num_workers, take ceiling and floor of this and create the constraint
My approach to solve constraint 6:
task of type q1/num_workers, take ceiling and floor of this and create the constraint
This approach does not work when there are predefined assignments as explained in point 3.
Additional clarification for point 6:

Say there are $5$ tasks of type $q_1$ and $8$ tasks of type $q_2$, then each worker must be assigned:

$1$ or $2$ tasks of $q_1$ type and,
$2$ tasks of $q_2$ type


This gets messy when $3$ tasks of $q_1$ type must be assigned to $w_2$ worker

This means that $w_2$ must be assigned less number of $q_2$ tasks to ensure overall similar workload
This also means that all other workers must be assigned additional tasks of types other than $q_2$ for balanced workload



Ideally, this should be a linear problem.
How should constraints 5 & 6 be designed?

For what it's worth, I made a video on the formula for fair scheduling.

First, constraints 5 and 6 are not constraints; they are objectives. There are various ways to formulate them. For load balancing, you could minimize the maximum number of tasks assigned to any worker or you could minimize the range (most tasks given to a work minus fewest tasks given to a worker). There are a number of other possibilities. For variety, you could maximize the minimum number of task types assigned to any worker. (I'm sure there are other possibilities.)
Once you have articulated those two objectives, you have to decide how to handle them. You could optimize a weighted combination of the two, or prioritize them and use lexicographic ordering (optimize the higher priority objective, then optimize the lower priority objective subject to the constraint of achieving the optimal value of the higher priority objective). Again, there are probably other (more esoteric) approaches.
This should work fine with predetermined assignments.

Makes sense that 5, 6 are objectives of the problem. Overall this is a minimization problem. The solution for 6 proposed by you, can it be converted to a minimization objective?

There is a downside of the possible objective for variety in task types. Ideally, each type of task should be assigned to workers in a balanced way.

Let's say if there are 5 tasks of type q1, then each worker should be assigned 1 or 2 tasks of q1 type
This can only get messed up when there are predetermined assignments. Say, w2 worker must be assigned 3 tasks of q1 type


Converting the variety objective to minimization: just multiply it by $-1.$

Predetermined assignments do not affect the validity of the variety objective; they just mean you will not attain the "ideal" value. Also, maximizing variety (the number of task types seen by each worker) is different from maximizing "balance" (each worker getting close to the mean number of tasks of each type).

Thanks. I will formulate the problem and solve it to see if this works :)
